# Amazon Video download location

Tags: amazon-video

Amazon Video now allows you to download certain titles from their library but you have to use their video player.  Does anyone know where those files get downloaded to on your phone?

Comment: Hi! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Did you thoroughly search/research for an answer before asking your question?  Tell us [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) so far and why it didn't meet your needs? This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself and it saves us from suggesting non-working answers.

Comment: Kevin, if you haven't found those files on your SD card (have you checked?), they most likely end up in the app's "private space" – which nobody but the app itself (and Mr. `root`) can access. They don't want you to copy them, they want you to use *their* products and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the videos are stored in `/data/data/com.amazon.avod.thirdpartyclient`, but they are stored in small parts as a different file format so you cannot play it through regular means.

Answer (score 1):

After searching the web I found the answer provided by Sonickyle27 which was the closest answer for my Android Moto Z phone. However I had approved the storing of my videos on my SD card, so I found the data stored in pieces using my file manager on the external storage (SD card): `Android/data/com.amazon.avod.thirdpartyclient/files`.
I use BETTER quality (medium), have 76 videos, 59 hours, 20.4GB in downloads. The file manager shows 76 folders with video and audio files that cannot be played outside the app.